# How can I have the OneDrive {itemId} before creating upload session?

Tags: rest, onedrive

I am using OneDrive rest API for my webapp using the code flow. I see some HTTP request samples in this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession) for uploading large files. It says that to begin a large file upload, I must first request a new upload session. But all of listed samples are containing `{itemId}` in its header. The question is how can I have the `{itemId}` before creating upload session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/drive/root:/{item-path}:/createUploadSession

"item-path" is the name of the folder that you will be uploading to. You can use folder name (eg: uploads)

Comment: I uploaded the file without any errors, but I can’t see the uploaded file in my one drive. I used a Business account.